# Javafx how to add content to an existing tab in fxml file dynamically

Tags: javafx-8

I have seen a lot of answers on how to add a NEW TAB to an existing tab pane of fxml file. 
I need to add content to an already EXISTING TAB of a tab pane.
Is it possible? If yes how do I do that?

Comment: If anyone is looking for this: Its done using setContent() method of the tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse it is possible. Just follow the steps :

1. Assign an `fx:id` to your Tab in the FXML
2. Use the `fx:id` to bind the Tab instance in the controller.
3. Now, you have the instance, you can add contents to it whenever you want, using [`setContent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setContent-javafx.scene.Node-).

**In FXML**

```
...
<Tab fx:id="myTab">
...
```

**In controller :**

```
class Mycontroller {

   ...
   @FXML
   private Tab myTab
   ...

   //somewhere in the controller
   tab.setContent(someNode);
   ...
}
```